# In shell scripting, how does a=$x work when there is whitespace in $x?

Tags: shell, variables, posix

The following command throws an error, as expected, because `a=foo` happens to be one command and `bar` happens to be anohter due to the whitespace in between.

```
$ a=foo   bar
-bash: bar: command not found
```

Now consider the following.

```
$ x="foo   bar"
$ ls $x
ls: cannot access foo: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access bar: No such file or directory
```

The above output clearly shows that when we write `$x` without double-quotes, the value in `$x` is split into two arguments.

So I would expect the following command to throw an error as well.

```
$ a=$x
$ echo "$a"
foo   bar
```

I was expecting that `a=$x` would be executed as if it were `a=foo bar` and it would throw `bar: command not found` error again. But you can see in the above output, that there was no error. It appears that `a=$x` was executed as if it were `a="foo bar"`.

I don't understand the rules here. What rules of shell require that when `a=$x` is executed, the entire value in `$x` should be considered to be a single argument?

Answer (score 1):

[Quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and [parsing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser) are subjects with many pitfalls. What you're seeing is because the command line string is tokenised (step 3) *before* expansions (step 5) happen.

Answer (score 0):

The `$variable` on RHS of the assingnment will work without quoting in bash.

I'm not sure with other shells. Therefore, if you *will use quoting*, nothing can go wrong (mostly). So, simply use default the quoted `"$variable"` syntax, you will save for yourself many debugging hours.

Only remember, in the double quotes aren't expanded

- the globbing characters, like `*`, `?` and `~`,
- nor the brace expansion like `echo "{a..b}{b..c}"` prints `{a..b}{b..c}` instead of `ab ac bb bc`

Command substitutions, variable expansions works inside of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace is used by the shell to separate words. Your first example

```
$ a=foo   bar
```

consists of two words, `a=foo` and `bar`. The shell interprets this as a command `bar` preceded by an assignment which causes `a` to have the value `foo` in `bar`'s environment.

The second example

```
x="foo   bar"
ls $x
```

is a simple assignment to `x`. The quotes prevent the shell from interpreting this as the command `bar` with augmented environment `x=foo` as in the previous example. When `$x` is expanded *without* quotes, it presents two separate words `foo` and `bar` as arguments to the `ls` command. That is, parameter expansions undergo word-splitting in this situation.

The third example

```
a=$x
```

demonstrates a special case in `bash`. Parameter expansions on the right-hand of an assignment do *not* undergo word splitting, so this is equivalent to `a="$x"`. `a` is assigned the exact value of `$x`.

From the `bash` man page under the heading Parameters (quoted is the 3.2 version, but applies to later versions as well)(emphasis mine):

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
> ```
>  name=[value]
> ```
>
> If value is not given, the variable is assigned the null string.
>   **All values undergo  tilde expansion, parameter and  variable  expansion,  command  substitution,  arithmetic expansion,  and quote
>   removal** (see EXPANSION below).

You'll note that two actions, word-splitting and pathname expansion, are missing from the list of things applied to *value*.

Answer (score 0):

I think below example will help you. I have set the debugger so we can see what is going on.

```
$ a='foo $100 bar'
a='foo $100 bar'
+ a='foo $100 bar'
$ x=$a
x=$a
+ x='foo $100 bar'
$ a="foo $100 bar"
a="foo $100 bar"
+ a='foo 00 bar'
$ x=$a
x=$a
+ x='foo 00 bar'
```

value of variable a is being assigned to X with in single quotes. So it will not give error.
Below is your example which explains in itself:

```
$ x="foo   bar"
x="foo   bar"
+ x='foo   bar'
$ a=$x
a=$x
+ a='foo   bar'
$ echo "$a"
echo "$a"
+ echo 'foo   bar'
foo   bar
```